# Equivalence of 2 types of Airy function definition

Tags: special-functions, airy-functions

### Question

How do I show the equivalence of the following 2 definitions?

Definition 1:

$$A_1(x) :=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_C \exp \left( \frac{1}{3}z^3 - xz \right) dz \tag{1}$$

Where $C$ is the path from $-3/\pi$ infinity to $3/\pi$ infinity in complex plane ([Integral path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snoJs.png)).

Definition 2:
$$A_2(x) :=
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \cos \left( \frac{t^3}{3} + xt \right) dt \tag{2}$$

### What I tried

$$I(\theta, a \to 
b) := \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_a^b \exp \left( \frac{1}{3}(re^{i\theta})^3 - x (r e^{i\theta})
 \right) e^{i\theta} dr $$

I understand:

$$A_1(x) = I(-\pi/3, -\infty \to 0) + I(\pi/3, 0 \to \infty)$$

$$A_2(x) = I(0, -\infty \to 0) + I(0, 0 \to \infty)$$

$$I(\pi/3, 0 \to \infty) = I(\theta, 0 \to \infty) \qquad \text{if} \quad \pi / 6 < \theta < 3\pi / 6$$

I can't show:

$$I(\pi/3, 0 \to \infty) = I(\pi / 2, 0 \to \infty)$$